# How to point all node js microservices in single port locally and consume it in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, microservices

In my React and node application, the is microservice architecture on the server side which is written in `node.js`, all the microservices are running different ports like

```
http://localhost:3001, 
http://localhost:3002
```

so on..,

I want to point all the services in a single port so that I can consume that services in react through only one single URL as a base path.
want to do this on a local server/ local system.
As I want to run the application end to end on the local server.

Comment: Use a reverse proxy. For example take a look at [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Nginx on WSL with Node.js resolved my issue, by creating a proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an API GATEWAY with a Message Broker (rabbitmq for example) and in your service in index.js just consume the Queue of message broker. before send the response to the msg broker and This message are consume by your gateway

Answer (score 0):

do you perhaps mean something like this?
you put this into the .env file

```
CONNECTION_URL = 'put your db url '
SECRET=...
BASE_URL='http://localhost:3000/'
NODE_ENV=env
```

as for front you can just call your functions by link
example

```
 const getItem= () => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/Items").then((response) => {
      setListItem(response.data);
    });
  };
```

Comment: as we have multiple endpoints in single service, so it wont be possible to make this  changes before production build